# Embedding a Metabase question in an iframe shows headers, legends and controls but not content

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, metabase

I have a problem with embedding questions from a Metabase 0.34.2 server in an iframe. When I embed questions the body of the item I'm embedding is hidden and styled to an absolute position and height too small to be visible.

I wonder if anyone has encountered this problem and whether there is a workaround?

I have built a little Sharepoint React app that embeds Metabase dashboards and questions in an iframe (using react-iframe-resizer-super). Metabase dashboards embed and resize fine using this app, but the two metabase questions I want to embed render everything except their "body" content.

This is the main code for generating the embedding iframe with resizer:

```
const iframeResizerOptions = 
  { 
    checkOrigin: false, 
    minHeight: 400,
    log: true
  };

function getMetabaseURL(props: IHelloDashProps) {
  var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
  var METABASE_SITE_URL = "https://metabase.blahblah.org";
  var METABASE_SECRET_KEY = props.secretkey;
  var payload = { 
    resource: { [props.dashboardorquestion]: Number(props.dashboardid) },
    params: {},
    exp: Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + (10 * 60) // 10 minute expiration
  };
  console.log('Debug Payload: ' + JSON.stringify(payload));
  var token = sign(payload, METABASE_SECRET_KEY);
  var iframeUrl = METABASE_SITE_URL + "/embed/" + props.dashboardorquestion + "/" + token;
  return(iframeUrl);
}

export default function HelloDash(props: IHelloDashProps) {
  return (
    <ReactIframeResizer iframeResizerOptions={iframeResizerOptions} src={getMetabaseURL(props)}>
    </ReactIframeResizer>
  );
}
```

My first embeddable question is a table that shows 12 rows when viewed in the Metabase UI or with the embedding URL in a tab on its own. When I embed that question in the above resizeable iframe it only renders 1 row in the table and that row is invisible because it has absolute positioning and height 0. The table controls show up – "Rows 1-1 of 12" – but only one invisible row when I would hope all 12 would render in HTML.

[image: One row of table should appear here but it doesn't]

If I change the rendered HTML to remove the absolute class from the div around the table (figuring I can modify the source), then the single row is shown. However I still have the problem that only one of the 12 rows is renders into the DOM instead of all 12.

`<div class="absolute top bottom left right scroll-x scroll-show scroll-show--hover" style="overflow-y: hidden;">`

I have another embeddable question with a legend and an area line plot. Again it renders fine in Metabase and in its own tab, but when I embed in an iframe with react-iframe-resizer-super the title and legend are visible, but the graph body is set to height 0 and is invisible.

[image: This should be a line plot]

I can hack the rendered HTML (below) to remove `position: absolute` and specify a fixed height to show the line plot.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 732.358px; height: 0px;">
```

[image: The embedded line chart should look like this]

Are there any tips and tricks to embedding Metabase questions in an iframe that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with `iframe-resizer-react`. 
I didn't solve the problem but a workaround is to not use `iframe-resizer-react`, and rely on react's ability to redraw the window coupled with normal css styling. The height is fixed, but the width auto resizes.

```
<iframe
  src={iframeUrlChart}
  frameBorder={0}
  height={600}
  style={{ width: '1px', minWidth: '100%'}}
/>
```